# Hadoop error while installing "cannot execute not a directory"

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop

Iam trying to install Hadoop 2.6.0 in my local system for some research purpose but when i complete my configurations and java installations the installation stops. It encounters an error at the time of executing the command

```
"hdfs namenode -format"
```

The error message i get is as follows

> "usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 276:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
>   /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 276: exec:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not
>   a directory"

I was wondering if anyone have encountered this error before.
Help me solve this.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME? What is it set to? http://serverfault.com/questions/515973/hadoop-usr-bin-hadoop-line-320-usr-bin-java-bin-java-not-a-directory

Comment: yes i have set the JAVA_HOME. Its set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386

Comment: Okay, do you know what configuration is causing hdfs to run java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle? Specifically where is that set, and what specific values is it being set to?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Hadoop 2.6 is not respecting JAVA_HOME variable. This might be a Java 8 undocumented feature. :-)

It is found in the hadoop install folder under etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
There is a line that sets the JAVA_HOME in there. It will append /bin/java to what ever you put in that line. In my case java is the default install in /usr/bin/java so I just set it to /usr and it worked.

Comment: My Java version is 1.6. I am trying to set up Hadoop-2.5.2 on it.  

`hdfs namenode -format` is giving error "cannot execute: Not a directory"  

I checked my java path using `whereis java` command, which showing /usr/bin/java so i set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr` in hadoop-env.sh as your suggestion.   

But now it is showing `export: '=/usr' : not a valid identifier` error occurring in hadoop-wnv.sh file.  

Can you please see this issue and help me @Michael